# What Am I? - A Word Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> If you add SP then you get a leap,
>
> if you add DU then you get the middle,
>
> and if you add SHA then everyone has it.
>
> I am an object, yet also a sound.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are a

> RING

because

> SP + RING = SPRING (leap)
>  DU + RING = DURING (the middle)
>  SHA + RING = SHARING (everyone has it)
>  and of course, a ring is an object and also describes a sound.